# Terminate application on exit

Tags: objective-c, macos

how could i make my Xcode application terminate completely when the user presses the X button.

Could you also provide some detail cause i'm sort of a beginner.

**EDIT:** Sorry for my vagueness, This is a desktop application.

Comment: What "X" button? Do you mean the Home button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender` method of AppDelegate. Sample:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender
{
 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the following message: `[NSApp terminate:nil]`.